# Unable to add custom headers to CloudFront distribution - using s3 as backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We are trying to put some custom headers to our cloud fount distribution, but its not working as expected. Following is the scenario.

We have a s3 bucket named "example-images" with all static contents, s3 bucket is exposed for public access. Has following CORS policy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

We are able to access s3 contents via URL following the sample output using curl.

```
x-amz-id-2: xxxxxxxxxxxx
x-amz-request-id: xxxxxxxxxxxx
Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 04:10:26 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Sep 2016 13:12:58 GMT
ETag: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 1630
Server: AmazonS3
```

Then we created a cloudfront distribution for serving these contents.

As per documentation we have following values set in "Default Origin"

> - Restrict bucket access = no
> - Oringnal custom headers   Some custom header
>
>   e.g. "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true"

In CF distribution "Behavior" we have following settings.

> - Protocol policy = http & https
> - Allow http methods = GET, HEAD, OPTIONS.
> - Forward Headers = whitelist
> - Whitelist headers = Origin
> - Object Caching = Use origin cache headers

Still we are not able to view custom headers when using CF Distribution url.

```
curl -sI -H "Origin: example.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: GET"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 1630
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 04:03:20 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Sep 2016 13:12:58 GMT
ETag: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin
Age: 1231
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Can you help us indentifying what setting we are missing here.

Comment: Can you add a consise problem statement to your question? eg maybe your key question is "We are not able to add a custom header to our Cloudfront distribution, which uses S3 as it's source".

Comment: If you need custom attributes attached to your objects, it should be trivial to parse out the x-amz-meta- in your client application.

Comment: Custom Origin Headers are headers CloudFront injects into the *request* before sending to the origin -- not into the *response*.  The client (user agent/browser, curl in this case) can't see them -- that's by design.

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom headers to the response from CloudFront / S3 using a [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) function. The lambda code runs within the local edge locations, but needs to be created and maintained in the `us-east-1` region.

The example code here uses nodeJS 6.10 to add the `x-frame-options` response header, but you can add any header that is not [restricted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-header-restrictions) by AWS.

```
'use strict'; 
 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const response = event.Records[0].cf.response; 
   const headers = response.headers; 
   response.headers['x-frame-options'] = [{"key":"X-Frame-Options","value":"SAMEORIGIN"}]; 
   console.log(response.headers); 
   callback(null, response);
 };
```

Create a definitive version of the Lambda, then set the Lambda Version's trigger configuration as the CloudFront `origin-response` Event type for your path pattern behavior.

The example code logs events to CloudWatch logs service for debugging purposes. If you don't already have one you will need to setup a lambda execution IAM role that allows a policy allowing CloudWatch logs actions to be assumed by `edgelambda.amazonaws.com` and `lambda.amazonaws.com`.

Basic Lambda Execution Policy allowing logs to be written to CloudWatch:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust Relationship allowing Lambda and Lambda@Edge to assume the role :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "edgelambda.amazonaws.com",
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

It would be better if AWS simply allowed the custom headers to be set using the CloudFront GUI but until then this solution should satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a header manipulation at the viewer response.
It simply adds a header to the response sent by CloudFront.

You need to use the new tool named "CloudFront Function".
https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v3/home#/functions/
It's running directly on the 218+ PoP of the CDN, not only on the regional one. The function needs to be written in JS.

Here the AWS blog post comparing lambda@edge and CloudFront Function: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/

From AWS blog post the most use case are:

- HTTP header manipulation
- Cache-key manipulations and normalization
- URL rewrites and redirects
- Access authorization

My function is simple:

```javascript
    function handler(event) {
      var response = event.response;
      var headers = response.headers;

      // Set custom header
      headers['custom-header'] = {value: '*'}; 

      // Return the response to viewers 
      return response;
    }
```

All you have to do is to attach it to your distribution, and it just works.